# Sith perspective of Star Wars saga

Tags: star-wars

If the "Star Wars" movies are the history of that galaxy from the perspective of the Jedi, are there any books or fan-movies, etc that tell it from the perspective of the Sith?

Comment: In Legends - there's at least Darth Bane, which has a Sith as the protagonist of the book...

Comment: The main Star Wars movies are saga of the Skywalker family from the perspective of the droids.

Comment: I wonder if this could be re-worded to make it a story-id question?

Comment: @Skooba Not unless it's a story Hack-R has already read and is trying to find again. Maybe if it's reworded to ask for a story from the Sith perspective in Disney canon it would be better. It would still be a list question, but the list would be well defined and presumably short. Jonah's answer would still be valid after the rewording too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes—and in canon!

Two specific examples:

[*Lords of the Sith*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lords_of_the_Sith) is canon, and features Darth Vader and Emperor Palpatine as primary characters (as one might imagine from the title).

> Vader completed his meditation and opened his eyes. His pale,
> flame-savaged face stared back at him from out of the reflective black
> transparisteel of his pressurized meditation chamber. Without the
> neural connection to his armor, he was conscious of the stumps of his
> legs, the ruin of his arms, the perpetual pain in his flesh. He
> welcomed it. Pain fed his hate, and hate fed his strength. Once, as a
> Jedi, he had meditated to find peace. Now he meditated to sharpen the
> edges of his anger.
>
> —*Lords of the Sith*

[*Tarkin*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel)) is also canon, and Emperor Palpatine has some scenes where he reflects on galactic domination and other subjects of interest to Sith Lords.

> Sidious assumed that Tarkin had puzzled out that Vader had once been
> Anakin Skywalker, under whom Tarkin had served during the war. Tarkin
> may also have determined that Vader was a Sith. If so, it followed
> that he accepted that Sidious was Vader’s dark side Master.
>
> —*Tarkin*

**The perspectives of Sith Lords are well-represented in the new Disney canon.**

Comment: Are these the only examples in Disney canon? I wonder if the question could be reopened to ask for a list of canon works. List questions are OK if the lists are short and defined well enough.

Comment: @anaranjada - There is another.